# Convert html with Persian characters to pdf using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext, persian

I have a Html file that contains Persian characters. I eant to convert it to pdf using iTextSharp.

I have written these lines to do it:

```
string HTML = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/Misc/Html.txt"));
Document document = new Document();
string fontpath = Server.MapPath("~/Fonts/BNazanin.ttf");
iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.Register(fontpath);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/Files/Pdf/test.pdf"), FileMode.Create));
document.Open();
try
{
    iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet styles = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet();
    styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, HtmlTags.FACE, "BNazanin");
    styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, HtmlTags.ENCODING, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H);
    List<IElement> list = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(HTML), styles);
    for (int k = 0; k < list.Count; k++)
    {
        document.Add((IElement)list[k]);
    }
    document.Close();
}
catch
{
    document.Close();
}
```

And the Html.txt is something like this:

```
<span>گرید</span>
```

But the output is something like this

```
دیرگ
```

instead of

```
گرید
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long time since I did work with Right-to-Left rendering of text but you should be able to set the RunDirection property to reflect the direction you need.

```
PdfPTable pdfTable = new PdfPTable(1);
pdfTable.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL;
```

Then it will be possible to add text in a cell that you add to the table, the cell will inherit the direction so it should render correctly.

Comment: How to combine it with the code written in try block? I mean how should I render the html in a cell?

Comment: Sorry but it was a really long time since I used ITextSharp, I just remember that the table element was the one providing the text direction property. A Quick search turns up a few samples that might help: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-ASPNet-GridView-Arabic-Persian-or-Urdu-Language-Characters-to-PDF-using-iTextSharp.aspx and Another one is this http://geekswithblogs.net/JaydPage/archive/2011/11/02/using-itextsharp-to-correctly-display-hebrew--arabic-text-right.aspx

Comment: You are right. It solved my problem. I made a PdfTable name table and a PdfCell named cell and set their directions to RTL and made a change in my code. Here is the change: PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();for (int k = 0; k < list.Count; k++){cell.AddElement((IElement)list[k]);}table.AddCell(cell);document.Add(table);
Thanks.